# HTML detect browser window width change without using javascript

Tags: html

Is it possible to detect a change in the browser window size (i.e the user resized the browser window) without using Javascript? I am looking for a minimalist cross-browser solution if possible for a static website.

Comment: If you want to achieve styling on window width change, then use CSS Media queries but you are expecting to trigger some action on width change, then in HTML alone, it's not possible. You would need JS for that.

Comment: That detects the size, but not a change in the size.

Comment: Nah - you cannot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CSS` with `@media` queries, instead of `JS`, but not only `HTML`.